# Could my drain be backing up in to my A/C condensate drain?

Tags: plumbing

I own a late 90's double wide trailer house, manufactured in the USA. The furnace is a 6 year old forced-air, natural gas and does not have a humidifier. The house has been unoccupied for about 6 months while the AC was set to *on*, at about 75°F, for the whole summer.

The pan at the bottom of the furnace has a line that is connected to a drain pipe with a 'Y' fitting that has been sized down to clamp the smaller line to it. It looks like they tried to form a P-trap in the small flex tube by making a U bend, held by a zip tie.  The drain line is also for the washing machine just before the 'Y' connection.

I found that the flex duct that connects the furnace to the duct work on the opposite side of the house is **full of water and collapsing from the weight**.

After I check the flex drain line to see if it is plugged-up, **how can I tell if this is condensate in the duct or could it have backed up from the drain**? This looks like a poor design how can I improve it or is it okay as is?

Comment: Could you include some photos?

Comment: I'm not positive, but am fairly sure that an air gap is required when connecting a condensate drain to a waste line.  Basically, there shouldn't be a seal between the waste line and the condensate drain. So that if the waste line backs up, it spills out instead of travelling up the condensate drain.

Comment: @Tester101 that's what I thought too. I'd send a picture if I could figure out how from this mobile device.